# Ubuntu 12.04 reply ARP request delay 10+ seconds

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox, arp

I'm running `Ubuntu 12.04` in `VirtualBox`, my server program is running in it, its IP is 192.168.1.105.

My client is running at 192.168.1.107. But the client alway took 10+ seconds to send a package to server. I `tcpdump` on the server (192.168.1.105), got logs as bellow:

```
16:58:15.559122 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.105 (88:53:95:2e:43:9d (oui Unknown)) tell 192.168.1.107, length 46
16:58:16.376719 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.105 (88:53:95:2e:43:9d (oui Unknown)) tell 192.168.1.107, length 46
16:58:17.300393 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.105 (88:53:95:2e:43:9d (oui Unknown)) tell 192.168.1.107, length 46
16:58:19.246464 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.105 (88:53:95:2e:43:9d (oui Unknown)) tell 192.168.1.107, length 46 16:58:23.238341 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.105 (88:53:95:2e:43:9d (oui Unknown)) tell 192.168.1.107, length 46
16:58:30.301090 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.105 tell 192.168.1.107, length 46
16:58:30.301115 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.105 is-at 08:00:27:80:81:85 (oui Unknown), length 28
```

Look at the timestamp, Ubuntu received ARP request but took 15 seconds to reply it. Almost every time my client send a package to server the OS issue an ARP request so the package delay very long.

Comment: Why did your MAC address change? What are you doing?

Comment: I didn't change MAC address. Actually, my client is running on an iOS device, i don't know why iOS keep sending ARP request.